# Is there a way to wrap text in Excel VBA form listbox?

Tags: forms, vba, excel, listbox, line-breaks

Is there a way to wrap text in Excel VBA form listbox?

```
item = item & WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ",30 - Len(item))
    subtotal = WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", 10 - subtotal_pad) & _
        "$ " & WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", subtotal_pad - Len(Format(subtotal, "0.00"))) & Format(subtotal, "0.00")
    taxed = "  "
        If tax_rate <> 0 Then
            taxed = " T"
        End If
    description = ""
        If description <> "" Then
            description = vbNewLine & "  - " & description
        End If
    quantity = ""
        If unit <> "ea" Then
            quantity = vbNewLine & "  - " & quantity & " @ $" & Format(cost, "0.00#") & "/" & unit
        End If

    lbxCharges.AddItem (item & subtotal & taxed & description & quantity)
```

This is how it looks:
[image: no line breaks]

but this is how it should look:
[image: with line breaks]

Comment: I think the short answer is no, why not just use another column?

Comment: Wolfie The problem is less with the columns and more with the rows. I want each item's description to be on the same row as the item, but on the next line. So that when the user selects an item, it is all selected together.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is why can't you just have the description in column 2, price in column 3? Alternatively you could put them as two rows, one for the item and one for the description, and then add some code so that when the selection changes they are both selected?

Comment: I will if it is the only option, but I would prefer not to just because, while in the example shown above the description is very short, there are times when the description might be a full paragraph.